# libc.so.6 error while compiling C++ program

Tags: c++, glibc, libc

I am a complete beginner in C++ and trying to run my first program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!";
    return 0;
}
```

Then I run, in the terminal:

```
g++ first.cpp
```

But it gives me this error:

```
/home/shikhar/anaconda3/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: undefined reference to `_dl_exception_create@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/shikhar/anaconda3/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: undefined reference to `_dl_audit_symbind_alt@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/shikhar/anaconda3/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: undefined reference to `_dl_audit_preinit@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/shikhar/anaconda3/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: undefined reference to `_dl_find_dso_for_object@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/shikhar/anaconda3/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: undefined reference to `_dl_fatal_printf@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/shikhar/anaconda3/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: undefined reference to `__nptl_change_stack_perm@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/home/shikhar/anaconda3/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: undefined reference to `__tunable_get_val@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
```

I am using Linux Mint 21.2. \

I am unable to understand any solutions on the internet for similar errors.

Comment: Try `g++ first.cpp -ldl`.

Comment: Those linker errors seems odd for that simple program. How did you install the compiler and the system development files? Have you set up anything special in the terminal for development? Is perhaps `g++` an alias for something else?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that doesn't work.

Comment: Try not to use `binutils` from conda. For example, run `conda deactivate` first.

Comment: @Shikhar Do you get a different error message? What platform is this exactly?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i am using anaconda

Comment: It worked when i deactivated anaconda!

Comment: Great to know that it helped.

Comment: @WeijunZhou  But why doesn't anaconda work?

Comment: Should I add this as the answer? (this if my first question on stackoverflow)

Comment: Anaconda sets some environment variables, for example `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which interferes with the execution of your program.

Comment: As for self-answering, see the help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Welcome to LD_LIBRARY_PATH hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was using the compiler through anaconda. Deactivating anaconda then compiling worked.

```
conda deactivate
```